# Restrict on the user level oracle trigger

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

This trigger works fine and restrict the os_users

```
create or replace trigger TRG_Restrict
before create on database
DECLARE
v_osuser varchar(500);
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
select sys_context('userenv', 'os_user') into v_osuser from dual;
if (lower(v_osuser) not in ( 'alex','hales')) then
insert into TEMP_AUDIT_users
  (ddl_date,
   user_name,
   ddl_type,
   object_type,
   object_name,
   owner,
   osuser,
   host,
   terminal,
   IP_address)
   VALUES
  (sysdate,
   ora_login_user,
   ora_sysevent,
   ora_dict_obj_type,
   ora_dict_obj_name,
   ora_dict_obj_owner,
   v_osuser,
   sys_context('USERENV', 'HOST'),
   sys_context('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'),
   SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS'));
commit;
begin
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
   (-20000,'Stop You Are Not Authorized To Make Any Change. Thank You :( 
   ');
end;
end if;
end;
```

But this trigger applied on  whole database i want to apply  this on selected users kindly share the something that will help.

Comment: `lower(v_osuser) not in ( 'Alex','Hales')` this trigger will never allow anyone to create anything because `Alex` and `Hales` both contain upper-case letters... When you say you want to restrict to certain users do you mean schemas? Have you tried adding a check on schema into the trigger body as well?

Comment: Besides, you should remove `commit` inside a database trigger. By the way, no need referencing `dual`, whereas using `v_osuser := sys_context('userenv', 'os_user')`  is enough.

Comment: yes i want to restrict certain users  mean schemas.

Comment: No i did not try add check on schema

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - the trigger needs COMMIT because it uses `pragma autonomous transaction` to log into the audit table.

Comment: @APC ok, thanks, but expression `should` might be wrong, but I `prefer` issuing `commit` from application layer. Since, I met some situations against `transaction integrity` (some records are committed, while the others are rolled-back) due to the procedures, functions ... containing `commit`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan -  Logging/auditing in a trigger is perfectly acceptable. Logging is about the only proper use case for `pragma autonomous transaction`, precisely because we want the logging to persist regardless of what happens in the transaction. There is no transactional integrity concern in this particular scenario. Given which, the trigger **must** have `commit` because we cannot have an autonomous transaction without it.

Comment: Why is this necessary? A trigger like this points towards a failure of privilege management. If you don't want  users to issue DDL don't create Oracle accounts which have CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, etc. Or revoke those privileges.

Comment: @APC as you know, commit takes all the changes to redo log files to be prepared to be written to the DB file whenever finds the opportunity. I met an overdated system which was needed to be shutdown and these shutdown operations might be able to cause such problems, because of commits at the halfway of the transactions. Commitment of logging is nice but some operations before/after are also impacted such semi-transactions. I mean I lived :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to add a constraint the same way to the user that connects to the database for that change, you would do similar trigger, and add a condition on top of it:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_Restrict
before create on database
DECLARE
  v_osuser varchar(500);
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  v_osuser := sys_context('userenv', 'os_user') ;
  -- condition on OS user
  if (lower(v_osuser) not in ( 'alex','hales')) then
    -- condition on user connected to Oracle
    if (ora_login_user not in ('SYS', 'OKTOMODIFY_USER1', 'OKTOMODIFY_USER2') ) then 
      INSERT into TEMP_AUDIT_users
        (ddl_date,          user_name,          ddl_type,          object_type,
         object_name,          owner,          osuser,          host,          terminal,
         IP_address)
      VALUES
        (sysdate,          ora_login_user,     ora_sysevent,     ora_dict_obj_type,
         ora_dict_obj_name,  ora_dict_obj_owner,  v_osuser,   sys_context('USERENV', 'HOST'),  sys_context('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'),
         SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS'));
      commit;    
      begin
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Stop You Are Not Authorized To Make Any Change. Thank You :( ');
      end;
    end if;
  end if;
END;
```

(here it is  assumed it is **OK to do modifications only connected to Oracle as** '`SYS`', '`OKTOMODIFY_USER1`' and '`OKTOMODIFY_USER2`' , from OS users `Alex` and `Hales`).

Comment: The general solution is correct but the whitelist is wrong. For instance this would derail sessions connected as SYSTEM. Certainly in 12c or later it would be better to [check DBA_USERS and allow users marked as ORACLE_MAINTAINED](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-309FCCB2-2E8D-4371-9FC5-7F3B10E2A8C0.htm#REFRN23302).

Comment: More generally, as I have commented on the question, this approach is unnecessary. Oracle provides straightforward ways of managing users' privileges, without the need for building brittle triggers.